# Создание указателя на метод std::vector::at()

Tags: c++, указатели

Требуется создать указатель на функцию at() стандартного вектора, например std::vector.

Но код:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vi;
typedef  int& (vi::*viFnPtr)(int);
viFnPtr fp = &vi::at;//ошибка
```

выдает ошибку преобразования функции at() к типу

```
int& (class std::vector<int>::*)(int)
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А **какой** из `at()` вы хотите перегрузить? их несколько...

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте указать точнее, с верными сигнатурами, что именно вы хотите:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vi;

typedef  const int& (vi::*viFnPtrC)(size_t) const;
viFnPtrC fpc = &vi::at;

typedef  int& (vi::*viFnPtr)(size_t);
viFnPtr fp = &vi::at;
```